# Macro to create cropped PDFs from PS files

Tags: osx, pdf

I have postscript PS images and have written a macro to convert to PDF and then crop to their boundingbox size. The code works fine, but I imagine there is a more straightforward way of doing this. Any help, appreciated. Thanks.

```
##!/bin/sh
echo 'Convert all PS to PDF in current directory and then crop according to the DAVE 
sizes (5x4in) 1.75,3.5in offset: in standard PS Letter size'
pwd
for f in *.ps
do 
ps2pdf -dEPSCrop "$f"
done
for g in *.pdf
do
pdfcrop --margins "10 10 10 10" "$g"
rm "$g"
done
```

Comment: I’m not sure why you’re unhappy with what you have.  I’m not specifically familiar with the programs you’re using (`ps2pdf` and `pdfcrop`).  It looks like `ps2pdf` takes one PS file and converts it to one PDF file with the same name but a different extension; right?  If that’s the case, you could handle everything with a single loop — is that the sort of improvement you’re looking for? … … … … … … … … … … … … P.S. `##!/bin/sh` is just a comment.  A “she-bang” line must begin with `#!` (i.e., only a single `#`).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, a simpler macro which doesn't require one to delete the un-needed PDFs. A single loop could work, but I wonder if ps2pdf can handle bounding box in some better way too. Thanks for spotting "she-bang" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531346/macro-to-create-cropped-pdfs-from-ps-files#comment983386_531346) that you don't want to store the unneeded intermediate PDF files.  Here's how to do that in a simpler shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for name in ./*.ps; do
    ps2pdf -dEPSCrop "$name" - | pdfcrop --margins '10 10 10 10' - "${name%.ps}.pdf"
done
```

The `ps2pdf` program can write to its standard output stream if you give it an output filename of `-`.  This stream can be piped directly into `pdfcrop` without having to store it in an intermediate file.  The filename `-` for the input file of `pdfcrop` means "read from standard input" (the data coming in over the pipe in this case).

The output file for `pdfcrop` will have the same name as the input file to `ps2pdf`, but with the trailing `.ps` replaced by `.pdf`.  This is done by the parameter substitution `${name%.ps}.pdf` (removes `.ps` from the end of the value of `$name`, and then appends `.pdf` to the resulting string).